# Modifying jqGrid looks

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I got 2 questions about JqGrid

- Is it possible to have column name in 2 lines instead of 1 line? I tried to change it from CSS side but it tends to break and gimped on occasion.
- Can we use another plugin on top of JqGrid, for example using combobox plugin on JqGrid to replace the dropdown box in JqGrid?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both is possible in jqGrid.

The items of `colNames` array contains HTML fragments. So you can use `<br/>` for example inside of the text. To increase the height of the columns you can use for example the following CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div { height: auto }
```

Alternatively one could need to use word or character wrapping of the text from `colNames`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935) for more details.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BootsrtapSelectInEditing.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404013/315935) demonstrates how to use [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) plugin which allows to search (filter) items in dropdown box. The demo uses `dataInit` callback of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) to "convert" the standard dropdown box in the more comfortable one.

Comment: Exactly the one i need. Your answers helped me alot Oleg. Thanks :D