# jqgrid: dynamic drop down from local json string data with search option

Tags: jqgrid

i'm looking for an help to resolve the following using jqGrid.
1)my data is already in json string before actual grid generated.
2) when I start enter the string in a add/edit form field, I want the partially entered string to be searched from the local json data and display the value in the field.
eg:- I have a form field Shipped Via, if I start entering "U" i need my dropdown should limit to "UPS" and "USPS" so now user can have an option to select  "UPS" or "USPS".

I tried many options like dataURL, DataInit.. but somewhere I tangled. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UsageFormetterSelect2.htm) (click on "Any" in the filter toolbar) created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) or [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FillToolbarSearchFilter.htm) (try to type `b` in the filter of the first column) created for [more old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5329014/315935).

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg for your quick response as always.
I'm sorry for the confusion. my requirement is when i click on grid record to edit or add new record, the opened form field (Shipped via) should have the feature to search for available values.

Comment: You are welcome! Look at [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19404013/315935) and [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BootsrtapSelectInEditing1.htm) for example. It uses select2 for form editing.

Comment: Thank you Again. I think this is the one I'm looking for.
I just in case, If any one wants to see all your demos in one place. Is there a place we can go and search for your demos?

Comment: I prepare the page with the reference of many demos as the part of documentation of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). I want publish first (I hope next week) the next 4.9.3 version of free jqGrid and then spend some time in the at least the parts of the documentation with some first demos. My main problem is **the time** which I can invest for it. Because I provide it for free I have to earn money for me and my family first and to invest the rest of my time for free jqGrid. I think the problem is easy to understand :-)