# free jqGrid: How to make label as hyperlink to new window on edit/addNew form?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

[image: .]
here Country Label should be a hyperlink to another window. I do not know whether it is possible or not. If it is possible, would you please share the demo here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature exists in old versions of jqGrid too. You need just add `formoptions.label` in the definition of the corresponding column in the `colModel`. Try the following example

```js
formoptions: {
    label: "<a target='_blank' " +
        "href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states'>Country</a>"
}
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/qzxwfquq/1/

Comment: Thank you Oleg. 
Is it possible to return a value from opened page and assign to this form field?

Comment: @GuruN: No. The second page works absolutely separately. You should consider to use Ajax call to get some data an click on "<a>" and then display some dialog **on the same page** over the Edit form. Look at [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19404013/315935) for example. Select2 control can make Ajax request to the server to show all countries available. If the user type substring then the dropdown reduce the list. After pressing Enter the chosen country will be inserted in the `<input>` control of the Edit form.

Comment: @Oleg: I am trying to use this method but it is not working. In my form label I have label:"<a href='#' id='displayDashNumbers'>Affected Dash Number(s):</a>" and on the main form I have $('#displayDashNumbers').on("click", function(){alert("here"}); but it never fires.